# VMWare Fusion: Present library instead of loading last VM

Tags: vmware-fusion

Is there a way to prevent default behaviour of loading last VM, and instead always present VM Library when I click VMWare Fusion from Dock?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

- Go into Virtual Machine Library
- Right click on VM's and select Get
  Info.
- Ensure Start automatically when VMWare Fusion launches is
  unchecked.

Also answered here:
https://communities.vmware.com/message/2747861#2747861